# "Filling up" an empty vector in Matlab by a for loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, vector, vectorization

I am trying to create a loop code in MATLAB that "fills up" the elements in an empty column vector of size *l x 1*, called *m*. As I don't have very much experience in MATLAB, I am unsure if this is the correct way to go about it.

**Note:** Seeing as *i* pertains to the complex quantity in matlab, I denote the *i-th* element of an array as the *ii-th* element.

```
l=length(A);         %The number of rows in the empty vector we seek as our output;
                     %so as to preallocate space for this vector.

q=eigencentrality(A);%An lx1 column vector whose ii-th elements are used in the loop.
l1=max(eig(A));      %A scalar used in the loop.
CS=sg_centrality(A); %%An lx1 column vector whose ii-th elements are used in the loop.

                     %Now for the actual loop that will "fill up" each ii-th entry
                     %of our empty vector, m.

m=NaN(l,1);          %create the empty vector to be "filled up".
for ii=1:l
   m(ii,:)=log(q(ii)^2)*sinh(l1)/CS(ii)^1/2;%this is the form that I want each entry
                                            %of m to have. Note how the ii-th element
                                            %of m depends on the corresponding ii-th
                                            %element of CS and q!
end
```

Is this the right way to go about "filling up" such an empty column vector, *m*, whose entries depend on the corresponding elements of two other vectors as above?

Cheers!

Comment: This is probably better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) , as it seems that this is functional code.

Comment: The [recommended way](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html#moreabout) to write the imaginary unit is `1i` or `1j`.

Comment: @beaker The point is that if all of your other code consistently follows the recommended practice of using `1i` instead of assuming that `i` is the imaginary unit, then it would be more robust.

Comment: @200_success I'll admit that `l1` looks confusing, but it's actually ELL-ONE, not the imaginary unit `1i`.  In fact, there is nothing in the code that refers to the imaginary unit... perhaps the `l1` should be renamed to something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this completely vectorized.  Vectorization is the act of processing data chunks at a time rather than individually as you're doing in your code. In fact, this is one of MATLAB's main advantages.  You can replace that `for` loop with:

```
 m = log(q.^2).*(sinh(l1)./CS).^1/2;
```

The `.*` and `.^` operators are known as **element-wise** operators.  This means that each value in each of `q`, `li` and `CS` will contribute to the corresponding position in the output.  There's no need to use a loop.

Check out this MathWorks note on vectorization here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Nice. Three answers suggesting vectorization posted within 10 seconds of each other :)

Comment: @mikkola hahahaha I know eh?  As soon as I posted, you both answered.  I'm debating if I should delete this answer now.

Comment: Yeah you should. And you will get a badge for that if you didn't already :D

Comment: @Dev-iL aw man... I'm 5 rep away from 200.  I'm deliberating if I should.

Answer (score 4):

You can **vectorize** all the operations, without using a for loop. This should work:

```
m=log(q.^2).*(sinh(l1)./CS).^1/2;
```

Note, that the **dots denote elementwise operations**. Usually this is much faster than using a loop. Also, just as a side note, you can then drop the preallocation.